# noun phrase and infinitive

Tags: infinitives, clauses

> He is asked to investigate [what the police believe to be the root of the crime (to discover the truth.)]

The first infinitive **to be the root of the crime**,
the understood subject is **what**, right?
Can the noun phrase be viewed as: The police believe what to be the root of the crime?

The second infinitive **to discover the truth** is a purpose adjunct,
and the understood subject is **he**,correct?

> He became what his [friends wouldn't expect him to be] (to prove them wrong.)

the understood subject of the first infinitive **to be** is **him** , and the object of **be** is **what** , right?
Can the noun phrase be viewed as: His friends wouldn't expect him to be what.

And for the second infinitive, **to prove them wrong** is a purpose adjunct ,
and the understood subject is **He**,correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your analysis is right.

Your paraphrases aren't actually grammatical, because you can't use *what* in that way (unless it is interrogative, which isn't the case here). But the understanding you have used to create them is right.